# bash delete a line from a file, permanently

Tags: file, sed, line

I have the following code for finding a string in a file then delete the line which contains that string.

```
echo `sed  /$string/d  file.txt` > file.txt
```

the problem is that if initially file.txt contains:

```
a
b
c
```

after deleting "a" (string=a) file.txt will become

```
b c
```

instead of

```
b
c
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because of the backticks. Do this instead:

```
sed -i /$string/d  file.txt
```

Note, if you want to do this in-place, you need to use `-i` to `sed` as `>` will destroy the file before `sed` can read it.

Comment: shouldn't we escape `$string` from regular expressions chars first?

Comment: @Khaledvic: Sure. This method also has issues if `$string` contains characters that the shell finds significant, e.g. `!`. Basically, if the content of `$string` is unknown, you need to carefully escape both regex and shell significant characters. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need the `echo` wrap, simply try:

```
sed -i '/a/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the command's output:

```
echo -n "`sed  /$string/d file.txt`" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

sed has an in-place editing option. It's more proper to use that in your senario.
e.g.

```
sed -i /$string/d file.txt
```

For the problem of your case, as the output of `` is not enclosed in double quotes, word splitting is done, by bash. And the newlines are removed.
To use echo in this case, do it like this:

```
echo "`sed  /$string/d  file.txt`" > file.txt
```